# How to prove this inequation of matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose a square matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is irreducible. It is given that there exits $i_0$ for $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}{|a_{i_0j}|}<\|A\|_{\infty}$$

Out goal is to prove:  $$\rho(A)< \|A\|_{\infty}$$

I was stuck at the very begining.  $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of A. I guess the essence is to prove the equality is not satisfied with the given condition. However I don't know how to prove it. Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to prove the first or the second inequality?

Comment: I am trying to prove the second inequality.

Comment: What does "irreducible" mean?

Comment: @Igor Rivin : I think a reducible matrix can be transformed into the form like: $$P^TAP = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      A_{11} & A_{12} \\
      0 & A_{22} \\
    \end{array}
  \right)$$  otherwise, it is irreducible.

Comment: P is a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 2):

**Gershgorin circles:**
$$
G_i = \left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-a_{ii}|\leq\sum_{j\neq i}|a_{ij}|\right\}.
$$

> **Taussky's theorem:** Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be irreducible. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ which lies on the boundary of the union of the Gershgorin discs $G_1,\ldots,G_n$, then $\lambda$ lies on the boundary of each Gershgorin circle $G_1,\ldots,G_n$.

We can apply the Taussky's theorem to prove the following:

> Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be irreducible and let
>   $$\tag{1}
> \sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|\leq\gamma\quad\text{for $i=1,\ldots,n$}
> $$
>   with a strict inequality for at least one $i_0\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then $\rho(A)<\gamma$.

*Proof:* Assume that $\rho(A)=|\lambda|=\gamma$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. By (1), all the Gershgorin circles $G_i$ lie in the closed circle $\Gamma=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leq\gamma\}$ and hence $\lambda$ lies on the boundary of $\cup_{i=1}^n G_i$. By Taussky's theorem, $\lambda$ lies on the boundary of each of the Georshorin circle $G_1,\ldots,G_n$. However, this is not possible since (1) holds with the strict inequality for some $i_0$ and thus no boundary point of $G_{i_0}$ is a boundary point of $\Gamma$. Hence, there's no eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda|=\gamma$ and thus $\rho(A)<\gamma$.

Now, set $\gamma=\|A\|_{\infty}$ to get the result.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am sorry I am not able to understand it cause I have never learned some of these elements before such as the disc and the circle. Could you please give another version by using simpler methods?

Comment: @HenriSHI Is it the Taussky's theorem  or its use you have the problem with?

Comment: yes, the difficulty is the theorem itself which is beyond my knowledge. I have only learned about matrices, and the problem was supposed to be solved within matrix notions.